I can't open NTFS External HDD | mounting error
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and when I try to open my external hard drive, I get this error:

Failed to mount "My Passport"
Error mounting/dvs/sda1 at /media/alireza/My Passport:wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Dear friends, thank you in advance for your help

Make sure support for the filesystem used on it is added to Ubuntu (ie. the helper program),

Most often you left Windows fast startup on which sets hibernation flag. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
or it could need chkdsk repairs, which you can only run from Windows.

My system is Ubuntu 23.10. I just had the same problem with you. I unplugged the NTFS drive without unmounting it and faced this problem when I tried to mount it again.
You will have to fix errors for that drive.
Many people are talking about ntfsfix, but according to this link
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/11qezjd/correctly_checking_ntfs_partitions_dont_use/
ntfsfix only clears the dirty bit but does not actually fix the error.
From the comments of the above link, I downloaded an apk file for Android from
https://apkpure.com/paragon-ufsd-root-mounter/com.paragon.mounter
Extracting files from it use the archive manager. In the assets/x86 folder, there is a binary file chkufsd.
Running sudo ./chkufsd -fs:ntfs /dev/nvme2n1 -f solves the problem.


worked like a charm, thank you so much
don't forget folx you need to make chkufsd executable and point it at the drive you wanna mount (which probably wont be /dev/nvme2n1!)

(addendum: resolved my issue on Ubuntu 24)

There is one catch, I try  to run  the above command, however, it didn't worked. When I gave the permission to run as Executable as Program after it run and worked.

If you can mount the NTFS drive on a Windows system, then unmount it properly from there. Afterwards it should be mountable on Linux.
